# Make: Uses of static pattern rules in make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to know the Uses of static pattern rules against normal rules in make. I an new to make and gone through some tutorials. I want to know when do we use this static pattern rules ? Could you please explain in brief ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverfow. Did you read [Chapter 10.5 Defining and Redefining Pattern Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) of the GNU make manual? If yes, what exactly do you need help with? Do you have a concrete example of Makefile on which you need help?

Comment: Yes, i read make file manual.. I know that, if we want to generate prerequisites based on target we use this static pattern rules. But, what is the purpose and for what requirement we use this ?

Comment: GNU `make` has evolved considerably since the original Unix `make`. Asking why such feature appears in it is a historical matter and very opinion-based, so your question is off-topic on StackOverflow. And `make` is one example of [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools (but you could use others, e.g. [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/), which has a different philosophy)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is mostly a matter of opinion. Notice that there are several [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools (not only [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)), e.g. also [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), [scons](https://scons.org/), [omake](http://omake.metaprl.org/), etc...

When you code in C (or in C++....) some project, you could have some C (or C++) files which are *generated* from something else (e.g. by [lemon](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) or by your own utility...). For such cases (pedantically you could call them [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming)), [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) could be useful (in particular if you have *several* such cases in a project). In other cases you generate other files (than object files) from C source (e.g. generating documentation with [doxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen)), and then pattern rules are also very useful.

An example of a large C++ project with many C++ code generators is the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler. And back when (in 2009) GCC was coded in C, it already had a dozen of specialized code generator programs emitting some C code. For these cases, pattern rules could be convenient.

Of course, pattern rules are a luxury. You could in principle generate your `Makefile` and have it contain a simple rule for each individual file. (in GCC, the `Makefile`-s *are* generated by [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) and [automake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automake) based things...)

If you observe and study the source code of most *large* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects, you'll find out that most of them do have generators for C (or C++) files. So generating C code is a usual practice (the original Unix from late 1970s did that already). Today, some software projects have most or even all (e.g. [CAIA](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2016/12/bootstrapping-caia-part-i-the-initial-domain/)) of their C code generated.